# Issue with PHP and osx 10.7 - runs via command line but not in browser

Tags: macos, osx-lion, php

I recently removed MAMP as I wanted to have more control over my machine and wanted to make use of PHP5.4  I installed using the script located [here](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) I cannot now not even get my default PHP that is built in to osx to work.  I am running this script with a simple `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` In a document in my ~/Sites directory.   I am really at a loss as to why this will not work.  I have php5 installed in my /usr/local directory via the link provided above and it seems like the main php is installed in /usr/bin

Any and all insight on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link isn't working.  To see whether your PHP installation is working, you could use the following code in Terminal:

```
php -f ~/Scripts/your_file.php
```

Replace "your_file.php" with the path to the actual file you want to check.  If it spits out HTML, then PHP is working properly.

It sounds like you might not have an HTTP server configured (that's what MAMP was doing for you).  MAMP or something similar is definitely the way to go.

The [next version of MAMP will support PHP 5.4](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=15303#p30147), and it looks like [BitNami's MAMP Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/mampstack) already does.

---

### Edit

I was unaware of php 5.4's built-in webserver.  There are good instructions on how to get it up and running at [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) (I modified this code so it should work in your case):

```
$ cd ~/Scripts
$ /usr/local/bin/php -S localhost:8000
```

Comment: Thank you @speedofmac this info is all great.  I ended up reinstalling MAMP PRO last night as I think it must have overwritten some configurations that I was unable to track down.  I was able to run my scripts in terminal like you mentioned above but no matter what the browser failed.  I am going to download the bitnami stack.  A bunch of google searching did not give me these results. Thanks again!!

Comment: I'm glad that you got everything up and running again, and I'm glad that I could help!